# Is there a way this change of coordinates can yield positive results?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system $x' = x - \cosh(x + y)^2 + 1, \ y' = \sinh(x + y)^2 - y$ and I noticed that I can take
$x' + y' = x - y.$ From here, I played around with the concept of changing non-linear coordinates by saying
$(t,x(t),y(t)) \rightarrow (t^*,z(t^*),1/z(t^*))$ because it gives me
$
\begin{align*}
z' - \frac{z'}{z^2} = z - 1/z
\end{align*}
$
which by some amazing coincidence simplifies into
$z' = z$ which has the trivial solution $z(t^*) = z_0e^{t^*}.$

What is the proper way to unchange these coordinates back into regular $t$-time to see if the system is solvable in some way? Or is there anything else that can be done to utilize this?

Comment: The squares are really for the whole expression and not something like $\cosh((x+y)^2)$?

Comment: I don't know what that means. $\sinh^2 - \cosh^2 = -1. $

Comment: Normally $f(x)^2$ has a clear meaning, but with the trigonometric and hyperbolic there is this deviating tradition of noting the powers. Is there, somehow, confirmation from the original formulation of the task for this reading of the formula?

Comment: I don't see why squaring would be ambiguous here, it seems like a pretty standard algebraic operation to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you set $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$, then you get
\begin{align}
u'&=v\\
v'&=u-2\sinh^2u
\end{align}
This is the first order system for a second order equation
$$
u''-u+2\sinh^2u=0.
$$
This is a conservative system, that is, all solutions move inside the level curves of the energy function
$$
E=u'^2-(u+1)^2+\sinh(2u).
$$

Comment: Okay, so I see you relabeled things differently which is fine, but I'm asking about the other technique of renaming the coordinates and back-substituting to try and find a solution.

Comment: That does not really work, you are assuming there that $x(t)y(t)=1$.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you haven't really explained why it doesn't work if that even is true in this special case, making an assumption and then testing it is perhaps literally the most common technique in all of mathematics across every single branch, so your point is entirely moot unless you actually explain yourself.

Comment: You removed half the system and introduced another unrelated dependence between the dependent variables. There is almost no hope that you accidentally satisfied the removed equation.

Comment: So in other words you didn't prove anything, you made a non-sequitur conjecture despite that the result drastically simplified in the new coordinates and despite that nonlinear changes in coordinates are very common in partial differential equations. I didn't remove half of anything, I levered the algebraic structure of a linear combination to deduce a symmetry.

Comment: If you set $x=z$ and $y=1/z$, then you get $xy=1$, this is simple algebra. Now if $x'y+xy'=0$ is not compatible with the ODE system, at least when restricted to $xy=1$, this functional relation does not hold for any solution.

Comment: But I didn't only change $x$ and $y$, I changed $x$ and $y$ and $t.$ The variable they are dependent on has itself changed.